# wiremock with 2 services on different ports

Tags: spring-boot, junit4, wiremock

I'm struggling a bit with wiremock. I have 2 HTTP calls that need to be made. They are on different ports. I have create 2 rules in the test on different ports. The 1 configured URL is working fine(I received the expected response in my code). The other never seems to find a match when it hits jetty. I'm not terribly sure what I am doing wrong.

I keep seeing this error in the logs:

```
service.document.SaveFileTest  Time elapsed: 8.584 sec  <<< FAILURE!
com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.client.VerificationException: 10 requests were unmatched by any stub mapping. Requests are:
{
  "url" : "/apiv1/registerChanges",
  "absoluteUrl" : "http://localhost:11887/apiv1/registerChanges",
  "method" : "POST",
  "clientIp" : "127.0.0.1",
  "headers" : {
    "Authorization" : "bearer ken sent me",
    "Accept" : "*/*",
    "User-Agent" : "Java/1.8.0_242",
    "Connection" : "keep-alive",
    "Host" : "localhost:11887",
    "Content-Length" : "939",
    "Content-Type" : "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
  },
  "cookies" : { },
  "browserProxyRequest" : false,
  "loggedDate" : 1585850180844,
  "bodyAsBase64" : "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",
  "body" : "{\"id\":0,\"entity\":\"document.document\",\"type\":\"createDocument\",\"entityRecordId\":10,\"authorGuid\":\"e49f9ecf-8ce2-4873-8274-b7ef7d539a52\",\"changeDate\":null,\"comments\":null,\"additionalInfo\":null,\"changes\":[{\"id\":0,\"field\":\"status\",\"fromValue\":\"\",\"toValue\":\"Status(version=0, id=1, name=active, authorService=AuthorService(version=0, id=1, name=accounting))\"},{\"id\":0,\"field\":\"function\",\"fromValue\":\"\",\"toValue\":\"Function(version=0, id=1, name=info, authorService=AuthorService(version=0, id=1, name=accounting))\"},{\"id\":0,\"field\":\"name\",\"fromValue\":\"\",\"toValue\":\"reports.txt\"},{\"id\":0,\"field\":\"authorService\",\"fromValue\":\"\",\"toValue\":\"AuthorService(version=0, id=1, name=accounting)\"},{\"id\":0,\"field\":\"owner\",\"fromValue\":\"\",\"toValue\":\"Owner(version=0, id=1, guid=cb36910c-5123-4ca4-aa96-d560bcfd38de)\"},{\"id\":0,\"field\":\"id\",\"fromValue\":\"0\",\"toValue\":\"10\"},{\"id\":0,\"field\":\"uuid\",\"fromValue\":\"\",\"toValue\":\"7925d481-c5dc-4193-b7cb-a441913d93f8\"}]}",
  "scheme" : "http",
  "host" : "localhost",
  "port" : 11887,
  "loggedDateString" : "2020-04-02T17:56:20Z",
  "queryParams" : { }
}
```

my test code is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(properties = {"spring.cloud.config.enabled=false"}, 
        webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {ServiceDocumentApplication.class}, initializers = {SaveFileTest.TestInit.class})
@DirtiesContext(methodMode = DirtiesContext.MethodMode.AFTER_METHOD)
@Slf4j
public class SaveFileTest {

    @ClassRule
    public static MySQLContainer db = new MySQLContainer();

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule changelogService = new WireMockRule(11887);

    @Rule
    public WireMockRule authRule = new WireMockRule(8901);

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webCtx;

    @Autowired
    private DocumentService docService;

    @Autowired
    private DocumentFileRepository docFileRepo;

    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webCtx).build();

        authRule.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/oauth/token"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withBody("{\"access_token\": \"ken sent me\", \"expires_in\": 200000}")));
    }

    @Test
    public void givenDocumentThatDoesNotExist_whenSaving_thenReturn500() throws Exception {
        final String testFilename = "new-test-doc.txt";
        final ClassPathResource newFileResource = new ClassPathResource(String.format("save-document/%s", testFilename));
        final byte[] newFileContent = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(newFileResource.getURI()));

        final String documentUuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final String authorUuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        final MockMultipartFile uploadFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", testFilename, 
                MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, newFileContent);
        final MockMultipartFile authorPart = new MockMultipartFile("authorGuid", "authorGuid", 
                MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, authorUuid.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        final MockMultipartFile documentStatus = new MockMultipartFile("documentStatus",
                "new".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        mvc.perform(fileUpload(String.format("/document/saveFile/%s", documentUuid))
                .file(uploadFile)
                .file(authorPart)
                .file(documentStatus))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());

        authRule.resetAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenDocumentThatExists_whenUpdated_thenReturn200AndSendChangeLogstoService() throws Exception {
        final String ownerUuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final String authorUuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        // setup - create dcoument
        final Document createdDoc = docService.createDocument("reports.txt", "active", "info", ownerUuid, "accounting", authorUuid);

        //setup - wiremock config
        changelogService.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/apiv1/registerChanges")).willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200)));

        final String testFilename = "update-doc.txt";
        final ClassPathResource updateFileRes = new ClassPathResource(String.format("save-document/%s", testFilename));
        final byte[] updateFileContent = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(updateFileRes.getURI()));

        final MockMultipartFile uploadFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", testFilename, 
                MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, updateFileContent);
        final MockMultipartFile authorPart = new MockMultipartFile("authorGuid", "authorGuid", 
                MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE, authorUuid.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        final MockMultipartFile documentStatus = new MockMultipartFile("documentStatus", 
                "updated".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        // perform call
        mvc.perform(fileUpload(String.format("/document/saveFile/%s", createdDoc.getUuid()))
                .file(uploadFile)
                .file(authorPart)
                .file(documentStatus))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

        // verify
        final DocumentFile savedFile = docFileRepo.findByDocumentIdAndDeletedFalse(createdDoc.getId());
        assertNotNull(savedFile);
        assertNotNull(savedFile.getFile());
        assertArrayEquals(updateFileContent, savedFile.getFile().getData());

        await().atMost(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS).untilAsserted(() -> {
            changelogService.verify(1, postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/apiv1/registerChanges")));

            authRule.verify(postRequestedFor(urlEqualTo("/oauth/token")));
        });
    }

    public static class TestInit implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            final MockPropertySource mockProps = new MockPropertySource();
            mockProps.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", db.getJdbcUrl());
            mockProps.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", db.getUsername());
            mockProps.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", db.getPassword());

            applicationContext.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addFirst(mockProps);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Changed it so that both services are on the same port and using the static method only for stub and verify. Not able to match the oauth request(which is the first call made)

Answer (score 3):

Just solved a similar problem - to launch multiple Wiremock Servers on different ports:

First, write a subclass of WireMockServer so we can set its port:

```
public static class MockServer extends WireMockServer {
    public MockServer(Options options) {
        super(options);
    }

    public WireMock getClient() {
        return client;
    }
}
```

Then, setup servers:

```
@BeforeAll
static void oneTimeSetUp() {
    if (myServer1 == null) {
        myServer1 = new MockServer(options().port(PORT1));
    }
    if (myServer2 == null) {
        myServer2 = new MockServer(options().port(PORT2));
    }
}

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {
    myServer1.start();
    myServer2.start();
}

@AfterEach
void tearDown() {
    myServer1.stop();
    myServer2.stop();
}
```

One thing to note: before using stubFor, you need to switch config to the server which you'd like to set the stub, e.g.

```
configureFor(myServer1.getClient());
stubFor(...)

configureFor(myServer2.getClient());
stubFor(...)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please, try on the setup start the Wiremock.
Take a look:

```
 @Before
    public void setup() {
        this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webCtx).build();

        // start wiremock here
        authRule.start();
        changelogService.start();

        authRule.stubFor(post(urlEqualTo("/oauth/token"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(200)
                        .withBody("{\"access_token\": \"ken sent me\", \"expires_in\": 200000}")));
    }
```